# Euler Angles Y value is affected by X and Z values - how do I zero them out to get a "truthful" y value?

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit, arkit, euler-angles

The effect I'm trying to achieve is to have an arrow pointed out from the camera's `pointOfView` position, aligned with the scene (and gravity) on the x and z axis, but pointing in the same direction as the camera. It might look something like this:

[image]

Right now, I have its euler angles `x` and `z` set to `0`, and it's `y` set to match that of the `ARSCNView.pointOfView.eulerAngles.y`. The problem is that as I rotate the device, the `eulerAngles.y` can end up having the same value for different points. For example, facing the device in one direction, my `eulerAngles` are:

`x: 2.52045, y: -0.300239, z: 3.12887`

Facing it in another direction, the `eulerAngles` are:

`euler angles x: -0.383826, y: -0.305686, z: -0.0239297`

Even though these directions are quite far apart, the `eulerAngles` is still pretty much the same. The different `x` and `z` values mean the `y` value doesn't represent which direction the device is facing. As a result, my arrow follows the camera's heading to some point, and then starts rotating back in the opposite direction. How can I zero-out the `x` and `z` values in a way that I'll get a truthful `y` value, that I can then use to orient my arrow?

Comment: Do you want a 3D object whose position/orientation are based on the *current* position/orientation of the camera at some moment, and stay the same thereafter, or do you want a 3D object whose position/orientation are always anchored to the camera even as the camera moves? The solutions are rather different for each situation.

Answer (score 1):

Do not use euler angles to detect 'real' or 'truthful' values.

Those values are always correct. To work with rotation you have to use either matricies or quaternions.

Remember. It is possible to define lots of 'euler angles' using matrix.

Each euler angle is relative to the previous one.

> SceneKit applies these rotations in the reverse order of the
> components:
>
> ```
>                1. first roll
>
>                2. then yaw
>
>                3. then pitch
> ```

So, to calculate the value  you angle I would suggest to calculate the vector and its projection to Oxy plane. This angle is not 'euler' angle.

Comment: I guess my question is "How do I set the euler angles of my arrow in order to have it laid out in front of me?"

Comment: @Andrew, ARSCNView.pointOfView.rotation quaternion is what are you looking for. But I'm not sure how do you want to set them. Manually? Write  here your work pipeline. Please, work with matricies and quats. They are dramatically better than Euler angles

Comment: You have got two reference frames: world and camera. The API yields to you the transform matrix . So, in order to create your arrow you have to calculate unit vector of camera's reference frame in the world reference frame.